# How can I change the color on the like button in django?

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-class-based-views

I did create (like and dislike) in my project and I need it when someone clicks on the button. the color will change to blue 
I saw something like that where I could create a variable called something like: is_liked = False, and I can place that in HTML by context to trigger it in (if condition) but it's not working with me so, How can I run the color on the like button?

views.py

```
# Detail question and Create comment
class QuestionDetail(DetailView, SingleObjectMixin):
    template_name = 'community/question_view.html'
    slug_field = 'ask_slug'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'user_slug'
    model = UserAsking
    queryset = UserAsking.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['my_question'] = UserAsking.objects.get(title=self.object)
        self_post = UserAsking.objects.get(title=self.object)
        post_slug = UserAsking.objects.get(ask_slug=self_post.ask_slug)
        context['summation'] = post_slug.likes.count() - post_slug.dislikes.count()
        context['comment_form'] = CommentForm
        comments_count = Comment.objects.filter(userasking=UserAsking.objects.get(title=self.object))
        context['comments_count'] = comments_count.count()
        # liked_post = User.objects.get(username=self.request.user.username).likes.exists()
        # context['liked_post'] = liked_post
        # disliked_post = User.objects.get(username=self.request.user.username).dislikes.exists()
        # context['disliked_post'] = disliked_post
        return context

    def post(self, request, user_slug, *args, **kwargs):
        my_question = UserAsking.objects.get(ask_slug=user_slug)
        userprof = UserProfile.objects.get(userasking__ask_slug=user_slug)
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        name = "%s %s" % (self.request.user.first_name, self.request.user.last_name)
        username = self.request.user.username
        logo = self.request.user.userprofile.logo.url
        c = CommentForm(self.request.POST).add_error('comment', 'error')
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment_form = Comment.objects.create(comment=self.request.POST.get('comment', None),
                                                  userasking_id=my_question.id,
                                                  userprofile_id=userprof.id,
                                                  name=name,
                                                  username=username,
                                                  logo=logo,
                                                  comment_slug=my_question.ask_slug
                                                  )
            comment_form.save()
            return redirect('community:question_view', comment_form.userasking.ask_slug)
        return render(request, 'community/question_view.html', {'comment_form': comment_form,
                                                                'c': c})
# Like post function
class LikePost(View, SingleObjectMixin):
    template_name = 'community/question_view.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        post = get_object_or_404(UserAsking, ask_slug=request.POST.get('post_slug'))
        if post.dislikes.filter(username=request.user).exists():
            post.dislikes.remove(request.user)
            post.likes.add(request.user)
```

models.py

```
class UserAsking(models.Model):
    userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, help_text='Be specific and imagine you’re asking a question to another person')
    question = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=False, help_text='Include all the information someone would need to answer your question')
    field = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CHOICE, default='Technology', help_text='Add the field to describe what your question is about')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ask_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes', blank=True)
    dislikes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='dislikes', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('community:question_view', kwargs={'user_slug': self.ask_slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.ask_slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
            elif post.likes.filter(username=request.user).exists():
                post.likes.remove(request.user)
            else:
                post.likes.add(request.user)
            return redirect(post.get_absolute_url())
    
    
    # Dislike post function
    class DisLikePost(View, SingleObjectMixin):
    
        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            post = get_object_or_404(UserAsking, ask_slug=request.POST.get('post_dislike_slug'))
            if post.likes.filter(username=request.user).exists():
                post.likes.remove(request.user)
                post.dislikes.add(request.user)
            elif post.dislikes.filter(username=request.user).exists():
                post.dislikes.remove(request.user)
            else:
                post.dislikes.add(request.user)
            return redirect(post.get_absolute_url())
```

how can I put the condition in the HTML page to check if is_liked is True or False?

Answer (score 0):

In Django Html use template like this

```
{% if query_set.is_like %}
...do something
 change back color like <h1 style:background:''blue></h1>
{% else %}
No change... <h1></h1>
{% endif%}
```

Comment: how can I put is_liked in this case, because the model that is responsible for showing the details, in that case, is (QuestionDetail) is separated to the model that does the function on (like), in that case, is (LikePost)?

Comment: Just send the secound model quereyset like if Test have queries {QUERYSET <...Like_this>,...} then send it like return render(request,'template.html,'{'query_set': query[0]})

Comment: and then without for loop in HTML template you can use like I define up

Comment: thanx so much for help, I add an answer and that's working with me.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a condition to get_context where that way did work with me. this way I didn't see before but it works perfectly:

views.py

```
class QuestionDetail(DetailView, SingleObjectMixin):
    template_name = 'community/question_view.html'
    slug_field = 'ask_slug'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'user_slug'
    model = UserAsking
    queryset = UserAsking.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['my_question'] = UserAsking.objects.get(title=self.object)
        self_post = UserAsking.objects.get(title=self.object)
        post_slug = UserAsking.objects.get(ask_slug=self_post.ask_slug)
        context['summation'] = post_slug.likes.count() - post_slug.dislikes.count()
        context['comment_form'] = CommentForm
        comments_count = Comment.objects.filter(userasking=UserAsking.objects.get(title=self.object))
        context['comments_count'] = comments_count.count()
        context['is_liked'] = False
        context['is_dislike'] = False
        # context to like the post
        if LikePost.as_view():
            if post_slug.dislikes.filter(username=self.request.user).exists():
                context['is_liked'] = False
            elif post_slug.likes.filter(username=self.request.user).exists():
                context['is_liked'] = True
            else:
                context['is_liked'] = False
        # context to dis-like the post
        if DisLikePost.as_view():
            if post_slug.likes.filter(username=self.request.user).exists():
                context['is_dislike'] = False
            elif post_slug.dislikes.filter(username=self.request.user).exists():
                context['is_dislike'] = True
            else:
                context['is_dislike'] = False
        return context

    def post(self, request, user_slug, *args, **kwargs):
        my_question = UserAsking.objects.get(ask_slug=user_slug)
        userprof = UserProfile.objects.get(userasking__ask_slug=user_slug)
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        name = "%s %s" % (self.request.user.first_name, self.request.user.last_name)
        username = self.request.user.username
        logo = self.request.user.userprofile.logo.url
        c = CommentForm(self.request.POST).add_error('comment', 'error')
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment_form = Comment.objects.create(comment=self.request.POST.get('comment', None),
                                                  userasking_id=my_question.id,
                                                  userprofile_id=userprof.id,
                                                  name=name,
                                                  username=username,
                                                  logo=logo,
                                                  comment_slug=my_question.ask_slug
                                                  )
            comment_form.save()
            return redirect('community:question_view', comment_form.userasking.ask_slug)
        return render(request, 'community/question_view.html', {'comment_form': comment_form,
                                                                'c': c})
# Like post function
class LikePost(View, SingleObjectMixin):
    template_name = 'community/question_view.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        post = get_object_or_404(UserAsking, ask_slug=request.POST.get('post_slug'))
        if post.dislikes.filter(username=request.user).exists():
            post.dislikes.remove(request.user)
            post.likes.add(request.user)
        elif post.likes.filter(username=request.user).exists():
            post.likes.remove(request.user)
        else:
            post.likes.add(request.user)
        return redirect(post.get_absolute_url())


# Dislike post function
class DisLikePost(View, SingleObjectMixin):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        post = get_object_or_404(UserAsking, ask_slug=request.POST.get('post_dislike_slug'))
        if post.likes.filter(username=request.user).exists():
            post.likes.remove(request.user)
            post.dislikes.add(request.user)
        elif post.dislikes.filter(username=request.user).exists():
            post.dislikes.remove(request.user)
        else:
            post.dislikes.add(request.user)
        return redirect(post.get_absolute_url())
```

at this moment, I add a condition on the view I already handle as you see above in the QuestionDetail model.